# Azure devops build co-relate with Jira Release

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, jira, jira-rest-api

I have pipeline building through devops, but issue/stories and release through Jira. My requirement is to using APIs to co-relate Azure Devops pipeline build with the Jira Release to track stories/issues we have delivered in the devops build.

I have to achieve this using APIs.

I have done lots of research on it, but not getting any working solution and a direction where I can spend more time to get the solution.